# MapReduce - Is there a reason for the Reducer not receiving the records of the Combiner?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a MapReduce application (I don't think the problem is code-related so I won't unnecessarily complicate this post) in which I am using the exact same class for the Reducer and Combiner.

This problem is as follows. If I don't use the Combiner, everything works as expected and the output file is produced by the Reducer. If I use the Combiner, an empty file is produced as result by the Reducer.

While checking the output I get the following:
[image: Output when using the Combiner]

My question is: is there a reason for the output records of the Combiner not being passed to the Reducer?

Comment: You to be careful as far as _what_ is actually being reduced to use a combiner or not. Taking it back to the classic WordCount example, a combiner is the same as the reducer because all that happens between the inner/global shuffling of the key-value pairs is a plain old summing up of (integer) values. In case your reducer is far more complicated (like manipulating `Text` instead of `IntWritable` values, or using a customized type altogether), you cannot expect things to go smoothly between the inner shuffling of the mappers and the global phase of shuffling before the data go to the reducers.

Comment: Actually, I'm using a custom type @Coursal , but I never thought that would be to blame

Comment: You can try creating a Combiner class yourself (there are many examples on the web) and try to manipulate exactly how you want the map inner shuffled data to be locally reduced, however it's hard to tell if this will really benefit _that much_ after putting extra work for a Combiner. Your best bet is trial and error, of course, but on the other hand if some thing's not broken you don't necessarily have to "fix" it, so I'd just leave out a combiner altogether

Comment: That was my thought as well :) Thank you for the input!